# Graphql mutation with referencing types

Tags: entity-relationship, graphql, mutation, object-type

I have a model like this:

Recipe:

- has many ingredients

Ingredient:

- has many recipes

IngredientList:

- Join table for both model classes plus some additional classes

What is the best practice for adding a `IngredientList` with a reference to `ingredient` and `recipe`?

Should I make a mutation like this:

`addRecipeIngredient(recipe {name: 'Wiener Schnitzel'}, ingredient {name: 'Schnitzel'})`
 
or

`addIngredientList(recipe: 1, ingredient: 1)`
With the second approach the recipe and ingredient would have to be created beforehand

Comment: Without knowing more about your application, I can't answer this as its opinion based. If you want a rigid set of recipes, go with the indexes, as its simpler to parse and less data. If you want people to be able to make their own recipes, you have to use strings.

Comment: It's a mixture of both of this use cases.
One the one hand I want to be able to easily add recipes with indexes or add existing ingredients to recipes (because i don't want to have them two times in my database). On the other hand I want to be able to create new ones when i have to.

Comment: It seems like this might be better handled on the database end. Take strings, but then query the db with an upsert, such that if the ingredient is not found, an entry for it is created.